# Concatenate two dataframes in pyspark by substring search

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two dataframes with the following structure:

Dataframe A:

| Current Accession | String |
| --- | --- |
| A_1 | AAAABBBC |
| A_2 | AAACR |

This data frame contains 1 millions strings.

Dataframe B:

| Accession | String |
| --- | --- |
| C_34 | RRRQ**AAAABBBC** |
| C_35 | R**AAAABBBC** |
| C_36 | WWWW**AAACR** |

I want to get a final dataframe by looking with the substring in dataframe A into dataframe B and create a new column with the new accessions found, results should look like:

| Current Accession | String | Mapped Accession |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A_1 | AAAABBBC | [C_34,C_35] |
| A_2 | AAACR | [C_36] |

I have explored join in pyspark but it needs exact match. Which doesn't work with sub-string matching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Column.contains](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.contains.html) can be used:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

dfA = ...
dfB = ...

dfA.join(dfB, on=dfB["String"].contains(dfA["String"])) \
  .groupBy("CurrentAccession").agg(
    F.first(dfA["String"]),
    F.collect_list("Accession")
  ).show()
```

Output:

```
+----------------+-------------+-----------------------+
|CurrentAccession|first(String)|collect_list(Accession)|
+----------------+-------------+-----------------------+
|             A_1|     AAAABBBC|           [C_34, C_35]|
|             A_2|        AAACR|                 [C_36]|
+----------------+-------------+-----------------------+
```

However, there is a downside using `contains` as join condition: a cross join is executed by Spark:

```python
dfA.join(dfB, on=dfB["String"].contains(dfA["String"])).explain()
```

shows

```
== Physical Plan ==
CartesianProduct Contains(String#71, String#67)
:- *(1) Filter isnotnull(String#67)
:  +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[CurrentAccession#66,String#67]
+- *(2) Filter isnotnull(String#71)
   +- *(2) Scan ExistingRDD[Accession#70,String#71]
```